# How would I use linear approximation to estimate $\sqrt{3.90^2 + 3.02^2}$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I want to use the linear approximation to estimate $\sqrt{3.90^2 + 3.02^2}$ but I am stuck.

Would I first replace the numbers with $x$ and $y$ respectively then get the partial differentiation for $x$ and $y$?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint $\#1$:** We have that $(x,y)=(3.90,3.02)$. Find $(x_0,y_0)$ such that $\sqrt{x_0^2+y_0^2}$ is simple enough for you to compute, and $|x-x_0|$ and $|y-y_0|$ is close enough.

**Hint $\#2$**: $(3,4,5)$ is a Pythagorean triplet.

Comment: I used 4 and 3 respectively. So I got $|3.90-4|=-0.1$ and $|3.02-3|=0.02$. Then I got z ~= f(4,3) + $\frac{4}{5}$(-0.1) + $\frac{3}{5}$(-0.02). Is this correct?

Comment: @Asaf what is the result with your method ?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: I don't know. I didn't sit down to derive and calculate. The idea is what's important, and to understand the method of "finding a reasonably computable point near by".

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I agree. +1

Answer (score 2):

Try to scale your problem so that you only have something about $\sqrt{1+\epsilon}$ with $\epsilon$ small. Than taylor gives you 
$$\sqrt{1+\epsilon}\approx 1+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Just for you to check, $3^2+4^2=5^2$ so your result should be something about $5$.

This gives you the idea to make the following

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{3.90^2+3.02^2}&=\sqrt{\frac{25}{25} (3.90^2+3.02^2)}\\
&=5\sqrt{0.6084+ 0.364816} \\
&=5\cdot \sqrt{0.973216} \\
&=5\cdot \sqrt{1- 0.026784}\\
&\approx 5\cdot (1- \frac{0.026784}{2})\\
&=5 \cdot 0.986608\\
&=4.93304
\end{align*}

Mathematica gives me as result for the original computation 
$$\sqrt{3.9^2+3.02^2}=4.93259$$
which is pretty good I think.

Comment: This is a linear approximation of $\sqrt{x^2}$ rather than $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. The idea is two differentiate with respect to both variables, rather than summation of both variables. True both ways will end up with a relatively reasonable approximation, but if I were grading such paper in calculus 2, I'd probably deduct at least half the points.

Comment: I disagree here respectfully, as you just add the variables, i don't see a reason to differentiate between the two variables (and the values have similiar values) so nor the absolut nor the relative error of both variables differ a lot. With the scaling I get even lowers errors, than you with your method. And my solution is more elementarry and less complex, so I totally don't unterstand why you would deduct at least half the points, would you please point out where my solution is not as good as yours ?

Comment: Dominic, the point of these exercises is not to get the result but to train the students in a particular technique. In this case the technique is first-order approximation of functions in two variables.

Comment: For sure it is important to train those techniques, but I (as a third semester student) would enjoy exercises where those techniques are adequate, and not nuking some moscitos. I didn't unterstand the question as an exercise.

Comment: Clearly if someone wanted to just approximate this square root a calculator would have done a vastly better job, and quite a lot easier too. Some things are actually useless, in modern times and are important as a concept rather than an actual way of solving *particular* numerical problems.

Answer (score 2):

Use taylor approximation:
$$ f(x, y) \approx f(4, 3) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(4, 3) (x - 4) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(4, 3) (y - 3).$$
This gives me $\sqrt{3.90^2 + 3.02^2} \approx 5 - 17/250 = 4.932$.